# Does using a sword and spell count as dual wielding?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the one handed weapon perk tree, there are perks that make dual wielding more effective.  Will the bonuses from these perks apply when I am using a weapon in one hand and a spell in the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. This perk will only apply if you have a weapon in each hand.